# Electric arc mechanism

Tags: electric-current, electromagnetic-induction, electronics, electrical-engineering, lightning

The prominent justification for ground fault interrupter technology is inability of circuit breaker to trip if intermittent low level arcing is generated as a result of the ground fault, so would you explaining the mechanism that may leads to generation of such low level arcing?

Comment: Cite your sources, please.  I.e., link to a web site, or properly cite the book, article or whatever you're looking at.  My (from memory, sorry) understand is that GFI protection is there to protect humans when they bridge from power to ground, and that there are _separate_ protection circuits necessary for low-level arcing.

Comment: Indeed, GFI is very different from arc protection. Generation of arcing is simple - the voltage on hot exceeds the dielectric rating to ground and makes a tiny lightning bolt. With ac supply it quenches when the voltage is not near peak. The object is to stop it before it arcs enough to set things on fire.

Comment: The "justification" for a ground fault circuit interruptor (GFCI) has nothing to do with arcs. A GFCI continuously measures the instantaneous difference between the currents in each of the two conductors supplying the load. If the currents in the two wires are not exactly equal-and-opposite, then it interrupts the circuit because that means that electric current is "returning" to the supply through some "fault" path (e.g., from the "hot" wire, up your right arm, through your heart, down your left arm, to the plumbing fixture gripped in your left hand, and back to the pole through the Earth.)

Comment: There is another new kind of circuit breaker called "_arc_ fault circuit interruptor." It's supposed to interrupt the circuit if it senses the "noise signature" of an electric arc somewhere in the circuit. The "justification" for _that_ is, an electric arc could be a symptom of a loose connection (e.g., a loose splice between wires, or a wire loosely attached to a terminal). Loose connections typically have high resistance, and they will get hot—maybe hot enough to start a fire—when heavily loaded. Note that, the arc at a loose connection is _not_ a "ground fault."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in a comment above, the real purpose of an arc-fault circuit interruptor is to break the circuit when it detects what could be a *loose connection* in the wiring.

> so would you explaining the mechanism that may leads to generation of such low level arcing?

The wires in the walls of your home have resistance, and when current is forced through resistance, it generates *heat.* For a ["lumped" resistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model), the formula is, $P=I^2R$, where $I$ is the current in Amperes, $R$ is the resistance in Ohms, and $P$ is the power dissipated in Watts.

The wires in the walls of your home don't have *much* resistance, and they are sized such that the temperature rise will not be dangerous even when they are loaded with the maximum allowed current. But, there *is* a measurable temperature rise.

Metals (and most everything else in the world) expand when they get warm, and they contract when they cool off. That tendency to expand and contract puts stress on places where wires are joined to each other or, joined to terminals, and over decades of current being switched on and off, the changing stress can gradually cause connections to become loose.

Loose connections have much higher resistance than the wire itself. Greater $R$, and proportionally greater $P$. What's worse though, is that the greater $R$ really is a "lump." It and the greater $P$ are concentrated at one small location. Loose connections can get *hot.* They can—they sometimes *do*—get hot enough to start fires.

Fortunately, loose connections also can be the site of tiny electric arcs that form when power is switched on, and those arcs emit electrical noise that an arc-fault circuit interruptor can sense. When the AFCI senses an arc, it assumes that the arc *could** be due to a dangerous loose connection, and it shuts off the circuit.

---

* A few decades back, I worked in a shared office space with an electrical engineer who said he was a member of the team that developed the first AFCI. I had never heard of AFCI at the time, and so he explained it to me. (Pretty much, everything I said above came from him.) Anyway, he said, the biggest challenge was making it *NOT* trip every time an incandescent light bulb burned out. (Typically, there will be an arc inside the light bulb when that happens.)

Comment: If we assume each wire of three phase supply that its insulation layer is worn out, as a cylindrical conductor through which there is alternating current (in skin effect layer) which is place at specific distance close to conducting wall. so would you explain the conditions in which electromagnetic radiation between the wire conductor and conducting wall lead to excitation of the metastable states
of nitrogen which have a large influence in
making ionization possible at much lower
electric fields and constitute a most important
step in the initiation of electrical breakdown.

Comment: No, Not if that's your question. Sorry, but I am not qualified to explain the physics of electric arcs.